# Is this AN on comparator with hysteresis wrong?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, comparator, hysteresis

Reading [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm94022-q1.pdf) of the LM94022, chapter 8.3, where is shown the following example:

[image: Application example of the LM94022]

I don't know how they get the formulas. I more agree to achieve something like this:

[image: Example that makes more sense]

taken from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262291/inverting-op-amp-schmitt-trigger-threshold).

What am I missing to get to the same formulas of the application example?

Comment: I agree with your derivation; note that if comparator Vout is not 4.1V then it becomes a little more difficult to solve.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNfJxJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basic Thevenin stuff. VREF is what you want. VREF = I3*R2. Plug in the equations to make I3, and solve. Put in VOUT = 0 for one threshold and VOUT = V+ to find the other.